# Query the fields attached to an entity in SQL drupal database

Tags: sql, drupal, relational-database

Users
[Screenshot users table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/360WZ.png)

field_data_field_user_first_name
[screenshot fields table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/swIHA.png)

What query should I use to get a table like this:

```
Uid  Email         First name

1    123@123.com   example
```

I have tried without luck:

```
SELECT * FROM users
LEFT JOIN field_data_field_user_first_name 
ON users.uid = ield_data_field_user_first_name.entity_id
```

Comment: SELECT uid, mail, field_user_first_name_value FROM users LEFT JOIN field_data_field_user_first_name ON users.uid = field_data_field_user_first_name.entity_id where bundle = "user"

Comment: Thank you. That worked perfectly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will get same result as mentioned above by using this query

```
SELECT users.uid as Uid,users.mail as Email,field_data_field_user_first_name.field_user_first_name_value as FirstName  FROM users
LEFT JOIN field_data_field_user_first_name 
ON users.uid = ield_data_field_user_first_name.entity_id;
```

Comment: you also need to add the where clause "bundle=user" !! Why ? Because that field can also be attached to any other Entity Type which is node, taxonomy, comment etc.

Comment: what if I would have another table: field_data_field_user_LAST_name, would I have to add a new LEFT JOIN, ON and WHERE clause?

Comment: yes, one short way to do is to use user_load($uid) in Drupal7.